# Получить информацию о ОС Linux

Tags: linux, ассемблер, nasm

Создаю программу, которая получает информацию об ОС ПК. Т.к. я новичок в ассемблере, то не совсем пойму, как мне получить нужную информацию. Можете, пожалуйста, привести linux syscalls, которые я могу использовать в своей работе. Знаю, что в корневом файле есть информация о системе, но как мне получить её с помощью системных вызовов?

Comment: Просто читать нужные файлы в каталогах /proc и /sys (например информация о процессоре лежит в /proc/cpuinfo, информация о PCI(e) устройствах в /sys/bus/pci)

Comment: Я думаю речь скорее о вызове `uname`, примеров гуглится полно, вот один из таких: https://github.com/hc0d3r/asm/blob/master/uname.asm.

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо большое

Comment: Более подробно это всё описано в главе "Chapter 7. Obtaining Information at Run-time" документа "POSIX Programmer's Guide. Writing Portable UNIX Programs with the POSIX.1 Standard".

Comment: @Sergey Благодарю. Буду изучать